# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException when using Groovy's Constructor Coersion

Tags: groovy

Why can't I Coerce my map into a constructor for IStringHolder?

When I run Example.main

```
interface IStringHolder {
    String getString()
}

class StringHolder implements IStringHolder {
    String string

    StringHolder(string) {
        this.string = string
    }

    @Override
    String getString() {
        return string
    }
}

class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doSomething([string:"hey"] as IStringHolder)

    }

    static void doSomething(IStringHolder stringHolder) {
        println stringHolder.getString()
    }

}
```

I get the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConvertedMap.invokeCustom(ConvertedMap.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConversionHandler.invoke(ConversionHandler.java:124)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getString(Unknown Source)
    at IStringHolder$getString.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at Example.doSomething(Example.groovy:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.callStatic(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:206)
    at Example.main(Example.groovy:21)
```

Why is the exception coming from the first line in Example.doSomething?

When I coerce the map to StringHolder then it works. What is going on?

Comment: How is it supposed to work? The interface has no concept of `string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Problem

The problem with this code is this line:

`doSomething([string:"hey"] as IStringHolder)`

The language feature of Groovy you're attempting to leverage here is called **Explicit Constructor Coercion**, which looks for a constructor within the `IStringHolder` class that it can call with the arguments you provided.

In this case, Groovy will look within the `IStringHolder` class for a no-arg constructor it can call to instantiate it, then it will look for a setter `setString(String str)` and call it with the `"hey"` you provided.

The reason you're seeing `UnsupportedOperationException` is because there is no constructor in `IStringHolder` to call, because it's not an implementation.

Switching the type coercion to `as StringHolder` does work, but probably not as you're expecting.  Had you provided simply `"hey"`, instead of `string:"hey"`, it would have done what you were expecting and what I detailed above.  This is because the map is interpreted as a [Named Argument Constructor](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_named_argument_constructor), which causes Groovy to instantiate your object using the only constructor it can find, passing `null` into it, and then calling the synthetic `setString(String str)` method with `"hey"` once it has been constructed.  While this yields the result you're looking for, it does it in a non-intuitive way.

## Solutions

**Explicit Constructor Coercion**

```
StringHolder stringHolderImpl = [ "hey" ] as StringHolder
```

Here Groovy will look for a constructor that takes one-arg of type `String` and pass our value `"hey"` into it.

**Implicit Constructor Coercion**

```
StringHolder stringHolder = [ "hey" ]
```

This is the same as above, except Groovy is using the left-side type to determine what the right-side *probably* is, before it proceeds with finding the constructor, etc.

I don't recommend this only because it makes Groovy assume too much, and IDEs like Intellij will complain about this syntax.

**Explicit Closure Coercion**

If you're adamant about not using the implementation class `StringHolder` you can create an implementation at runtime via:

```
IStringHolder stringHolderImpl = { getString: "hey" } as IStringHolder
```

This creates a closure which satisfies the `IStringHolder` contract, so it can be easily cast to an implementation of it.

**Implicit Closure Coercion**

```
IStringHolder stringHolderImpl = { getString: "hey" }
```

Again I don't really recommend this style, but it works.

## My Thoughts

I'm a fan of explicit constructor coercion due to the explicit nature and because it doesn't require the overhead of creating a closure.  I'll use explicit closure coercion from time to time when I need an implementation of a class that only needs to exist at runtime.

What's the best option?  You'll have to determine that for yourself!

## tl;dr

- You were trying to coerce to an interface instead of an implementation
- You tried to use a Named Argument Constructor for the coercion when you needed to use a [Positional Argument Constructor](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_positional_argument_constructor)